# How to distribute iOS App that use data from local server without iOS Enterprise program in 2020?

Tags: ios, app-distribution

Apple app store doesn't accept our iOS app because it needs to use local server data, like login to app. They said they need to check inside data.

We need to install iOS app for members who will connect to local server with WIFI. Even if I can make (.ipa) file, app can't be installed without jailbreak. Even if I can install app by downloading .ipa file directly on jailbreaked iPhone, app doesn't run on real iPhone although app runs smoothly on emulator.

Apple Developer Enterprise Program account — It’s $299 per year
As our group will run more than 10 years, we are finding cost saving ways.
Can anyone share me how to distribute iOS App in local server without iOS developer program?

***Please down vote only if you can show me the solution or link to the answer.***

Comment: Your options are enterprise program, a B2B app delivered by the regular developer membership (but you still have to submit to Apple for review, so they need to be to bale to run your app across the Internet) or develop a web app rather than a native app

Comment: Our app is in a similar condition... we set up a temporary server (not my department, but I believe we use Azure) so the reviewer can connect and use the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can distribute it through Testflight and get 10,000 installs

Comment: I want to distribute app to members (customers). Need easier way to download and install to their iphones. And as I said before, data will be retrieved and stored to LOCAL web server. Only registered from local web server members can login to app.

Comment: Then you only have to apply for the enterprise program